# Batch File to check file's modified date and then compare it to another

Tags: batch-file

Say that I have a few files with that have different date modified times. Some of them differ by days, some only by hours or minutes. How can I access the date modified time and then compare them, and sort them by day?

For example, if I have this set of files below:

```
Date                    File
2015/07/29  15:31       A1
2015/07/29  16:00       A2
2015/07/30  15:00       B1
2015/07/30  15:05       B2
```

and I want the output to be:

```
2015/07/29  16:00
2015/07/30  15:05
```

As you can see, I don't care about the file's name, I just want to know the last date modified time per day.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Command which would give the list of files in sorted order of their last modified date/time.

```
dir /a:-D /O:-D /T:W
```

Explanation to the options used with dir command

**/a:-D :** would list only file names in the directory.

**/O:-D :** sort Files in order of latest first by date.

**/T:W  :** would list the files with last modified/Last written time.

Comment: But like I posted in my sample output, I don't care for the names. I just want the times, without having to delete the files. I can of course just go to the folder itself and sort by date modified, but with the number of files I have I don't want that. I just want it to display the last time of each of the days.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns a list of unique modification dates and the latest times for each day, the most recent date appears first:

```
@echo off
set FOLDER=D:\StackOverflow\BatchTesting
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set PREVIOUS=
for /F "skip=4 tokens=1-2" %%A in ('dir /N /A:-D /O:-D /T:W "%FOLDER%"') do (
    if not "%%B"=="File(s)" (
        if not "%%B"=="Dir(s)" (
            if not "%%A"=="!PREVIOUS!" echo %%A  %%B
            set PREVIOUS=%%A
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

### Explanation:

Core element of this approach is the `dir` command, applied on the folder given by the variable `FOLDER`, which outputs something like this:

```
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000

 Directory of D:\StackOverflow\BatchTesting

2015/07/31  00:30                12 foo.txt
2015/07/30  20:15               512 bar.txt
2015/07/30  18:45             1'432 somelog.log
2015/07/30  09:00               573 testscpt.bat
2015/07/28  17:10                99 crapfile.tmp
               5 File(s)          2'628 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  100'000'000'000 bytes free
```

The `for` loop parses the `dir` output, skipping the header and extracting the first two (whitespace-separated) tokens, which are date and time, line after line. The `dir` options are set so that only files are listed (no directories) and sorted in descending order with respect to the modification date/time.

The two outer `if` statements make sure that the summary lines of the `dir` output are ignored (adapt the search words accordingly if working on a non-English system).

The inner `if` statement compares the date portion of the current parsed line with the previous one, which is stored in variable `PREVIOUS`. Its value is stored *after* the comparison to be used for the next loop iteration.

So the final output of this batch script - when fed with the example above - will be:

```
2015/07/31  00:30
2015/07/30  20:15
2015/07/28  17:10
```

To write the output into a text file, call the batch file (let's call it `daytimes.bat`) with redirection:

```
daytimes.bat > YourTextFile.txt
```

Comment: To write the output into a text file, call the batch file (let's call it `daytimes.bat`) with redirection: `daytimes.bat > YourTextFile.txt`.

Comment: Is there any way that I can in the output I only have one output for each day? This is the biggest issue that I'm trying to stress that no one seems to recognize. Because the folder that I'll use this code for has over 1000+ files, so just sorting it like this will be a bit much to sort through.

Comment: I completed my answer, providing the output related to the `dir` example, and adding the method to put that into a text file. I think, this is exactly what you wanted (please let me know if I'm wrong).