# How to make a list of the last modified dates of each day in a new text file in batch

Tags: batch-file

Say that I have a few files with that have different date modified times. Some of them differ by days, some only by hours or minutes. How can I access the date modified time and then compare them, and sort them by day?

For example, if I have this set of files below:

```
Date                    File
2015/07/29  15:31       A1
2015/07/29  16:00       A2
2015/07/30  15:00       B1
2015/07/30  15:05       B2
```

and I want the output to be in a new text document:

```
2015/07/29  16:00
2015/07/30  15:05
```

As you can see, I don't care about the file's name, I just want to know the last date modified time per day. I only want the last of each day, I don't want it to merely be sorted as everyone seems to be suggesting.

Comment: Why are you asking [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31733158/5047996) twice??

Comment: It wasn't answered the first time. Everyone assumes I just want it sorted, BUT I DON'T. I want ONLY the last file time of each day, hence my output. Everyone's suggestion would not do what I ask.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31735469/5047996) for your first post -- hope it helps! Please do NOT ask duplicate questions here! You should edit your (original) question, clarify its title, improve your explanations,... -- and be a bit more patient; keep in mind that [tag:batch-file] is not that frequently visited as [tag:python], for example... thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the other post, it really helps me learn what's happening. But that just sorts the folder, but doesn't output a file like I asked in both these posts. Hence, it's not answering the question.